# php-smpp Library not working and fails after two to three SMS

Tags: smpp, php-socket

it is very first time i'm messing with sockets , and read many quotes that this is not for newbies.

so problem is i'm using [php smpp library](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp/tree/windows-compatible)  for sending `SMS` which works fine but after delivering two to three SMS delivery fails with following warning

`Warning: stream_socket_sendto() [function.stream-socket-sendto]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'`,  **and to make it work again i need to restart` apache**.

Following is write function which throwing exception

```
public function write($buf) {
    $null = null;
    $write = array($this->handle_);

    // keep writing until all the data has been written
    while (strlen($buf) > 0) {
        // wait for stream to become available for writing
        $writable = @stream_select($null, $write, $null, $this->sendTimeoutSec_, $this->sendTimeoutUsec_);
        if ($writable > 0) {
            // write buffer to stream
            $written = stream_socket_sendto($this->handle_, $buf);
            if ($written === -1 || $written === false) {
                throw new TTransportException('TSocket: Could not write '.$written.' bytes '.
                $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
            }
            // determine how much of the buffer is left to write
            $buf = substr($buf, $written);
        } else if ($writable === 0) {
            throw new TTransportException('TSocket: timed out writing '.strlen($buf).' bytes from '.
            $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
        } else {
            throw new TTransportException('TSocket: Could not write '.strlen($buf).' bytes '.
            $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
        }
    }
}
```

Please anyone can put some light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the bug which i won't able to identify/ rectify. then i used an other library from http://www.codeforge.com/read/171085/smpp.php__html and it really saved me.